# Determine who runs a Corda schedule state

Tags: corda

I am implementing a `LinearState` that is also a `SchedulableState` in a Cordapp. The state object is shared and agreed among 3 parties when it's created and stored in each of their vaults. However, when the scheduled activity comes around, all 3 of the nodes that stored it seem to trigger the next flow.

How do I select just one of these nodes to run the flow?

I can't see anything about this on the scheduling page: https://docs.corda.net/event-scheduling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the definition of [`FixingRoleDecider`](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/d027b5b8f2bb00ef7f39d6760b658ccc4c165b43/samples/irs-demo/cordapp/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/irs/flows/FixingFlow.kt#L120).

When the scheduled activity occurs, the `FixingRoleDecider` flow is started. `FixingRoleDecider` then uses an `if` condition to only start the flow on the correct node.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a workaround rather than a solution: one way would be to check in your schedulableFlow, if Node is supposed to run the flow or not. you can hardcode the Party which is supposed to run the node, compare if it's the same party running the flow, if not return null. or put the info in an oracle and query the oracle to see if the node has the permission to run the required flow.